# One variable modulo equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was attempting Wiener's Attack on RSA with a simple example and I came to a one variable modulo equation which I managed to solve with brute-force but I think it must be easier than that with some algorithm/formula.

here it is.

$e * d \equiv 1 \mod phi(N)$

e and phi(N) are known: e = 5 550 641 and phi(N) = 15 726 816

so it gives us: $5 550 641 * d \equiv 1 \mod phi(N)$

I got the answer, d = 17 but as I mentioned only with brute force, is there any formula or algorithm for solving this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving $5550641 d \equiv 1 \pmod{15726816}$ can be done very quickly. This is called **finding the modular inverse** of $5550641$ modulo $15726816$. The best way to do this is through the Euclidean Algorithm (along with back substitution. This is sometimes called the Extended Euclidean Algorithm).

This is a topic that has been asked extensively on this site, so I will link you to some examples.

1. In [Modular Inverses](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/163107/9754) it is asked to find the modular inverse of $19$ mod $141$. This is the same question as yours, but with different numbers.
2. In [Using Extended Euclidean Algorithm for $85$ and $45$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/977552/9754) we have another example with still different numbers.
3. In [How to use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm manually?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/85830/9754) some details are given in a more general context, with an eye towards computing by hand. I'll note that in your case, you should really use a computer. But I'm assuming that you want to understand, as otherwise you could just prompt [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5550641+x+%3D+1+mod+15726816).

Good luck!

Comment: Back substitution is *not* the *Extended Euclidean algorithm*. The E.E.A. is a special layout which directly outputs the g.c.d. and the coefficients of a *Bézout's relation* between two numbers (One step further yields the l.c.m.). See for instance my answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2099165/how-to-solve-min-x-in-mathbb-n-0-quad-x-cdot-714-quad-mod-quad-1972-qua/2099198#2099198).

Comment: @ mixedmath, Done, Thanks !

Comment: @Bernard The "extended Euclidean algorithm" is an overloaded term that may refer to many different variants of this algorithm (including the common back-substitution method). I do agree however that the augmented form  using equations or matrices is better (I present that [here in an elementary form)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85830/how-to-use-the-extended-euclidean-algorithm-manually/85841#85841) since it is much less error-prone, easier to remember, and motivates generalizations such as (Hermite-)Smith normal form, etc.

Comment: @Bernard I prefer the [fractional form](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2053174/242) of the extended Eucldean algorithm, but that's a little tricky for novices.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: It seems like you work within the class group of fractionary ideals. Am I right?

Comment: @Bernard It's much simpler: I'm just overloading fractional notation to denote solution sets of linear equations in $\,\Bbb Z/m\,$ (which is what you obtain if you optimize the EEA by ignoring one of the Bezout coefficients). It's a natural generalization of the fractional form of [Gauss's algorithm](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) to the case of non-prime modulus.

Comment: Ah! I  think I'll have to study it in more detail. Is it easy to implement it?

Comment: @Bernard Yes. It's equivalent to what you do, except working with only one column (or row) of Bezout coefficients, and expressing the resulting linear modular equations in (multi-valued) fraction notation.

Comment: @Bernard While linking I just noticed that Marc van Leeuwen also  mentioned a form of this [well-known EEA  optimization here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/252923/242) You might find that version an easier introduction since it doesn't require simultaneous understanding of the fractional language (though that is easy).

Comment: Yes, this version is perfectly clear. I'll study in more detail the connection with your way of obtaining modular inverses.